# Are other VPN members than me can access my private network?

Tags: networking, vpn

My private computer is connected via VPN to my emplorer's office network and is also connected to my private home network. Are other employees (which are also connected to the office VPN) able to access my private home network through the VPN connection?

Comment: No, or nobody would use a VPN. middle word in VPN being Private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***In theory*** most VPNs presents itself as a "virtual" network adaptor so that the operating system itself deals with the separation of networks.

A program running locally on your machine may have access to both your own network and the work network and as such will be set up to access specific network resources. Unless you (or your IT people) have specifically set up a gateway or routing table that bridges between your work and home networks then there is no way they can access your home network, unless a program you are using for work is explicitly doing something on both.

Having that bridge set up is bad from a company security perspective as not only would they have access to your network, but potentially any computer on your network could have access to theirs. I would be surprised if any company would allow this. Many corporate VPN solutions actively shut down and lock all network traffic apart from the VPN tunnel to enforce security and isolation on "untrusted" networks.

The answer is "probably not", but only your IT people know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not.  We set up all VPN memberships so they are unique and do not cross over. None of or clients can see other VPN setups.

You may wish (to be absolutely certain) to verify this with your company IT administrator .